# three problems with qtcreator android and qml

Tags: android, c++, qml

I try to write something in `QTCreator` in c++ and I have three small problems.
Two problems relate to `QML`, one is with `QGeoCoordinate`.
I am running application in my phone with Android.

*Problem 1:*

I want to import `QtPositioning` 5.2 to my project and create a map. I can import this but when I want to use a type, for example "map" I can't. In design I don't see more options for QtPositioning. I only see the options as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFlBe.jpg).

What and where I have to add to the project?

*Problem 2:*

I have two text areas and button "send" in application. In first I write variance "a", in second I write variance "b". Button "send" clears a text area. 
When I have the cursor in text area for "b" and click the button, only text area for "a" is clearing.
When I have the cursor in text area for "a" and click button, only text area for "b" is clearing. 
When I have the cursor in text area "a", next in text area "b" and finally in text area "a" the button is clearing both.
How fixed this would be when i have a cursor in text area a clearing in the two?

This is the code:

```
button1.onClicked: {chleb.wysyl(textArea1.text, textArea2.text);
textArea1.text = "", textArea2.text=""}
```

chleb and wysyl this is a function who send a text to .cpp for operation.

Problem 3:
I have this code:

```
QGeoCoordinate a;

QString coordStr;
qDebug() << a.DegreesMinutesSecondsWithHemisphere;
coordStr = a.toString();
qDebug() << coordStr;
```

First debug show me: "5"
Second debug show me: ""
I'm not a sure what does it mean. My application reads a position but can't show me it? Or it can't read a position?
In android manifest I give the application all permissions where I see word "location.

Comment: Please separate your question into 3 distinct questions. Please review [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I didn't want to make a spam.

Comment: No I do not think your question is spam. If you think about it, what would a good answer look like? You want an answer to be nicely wrapped up and solving the issue. However when you ask 3 questions now someone has to go to triple the effort to solve the problem, and that means you are unlikely to get an answer because people are generally lazy. At SO we all want to get answers. I hope you get yours!

Comment: [S.S.C.C.E.'s](http://sscce.org/) are greatly appreciated and will likely result in answers to your questions.

Comment: 1) Qt Positioning provides just the position, you need to import also *Qt Location* for `Map` and other visual types, 2) show the code, no one is going to answer that part like that, 3) the coordinate is invalid.

Comment: Oh, also the comma is totally wrong: just divide the two line of code of question 2) with either a carriege return or a semicolon.